# Xamarin Android, get contact mobile number by using CursorLoader with selection and selection args

Tags: xamarin.android, selection, android-contacts, feature-selection, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to get contact details of a contact that the user picks from the contacts list in Android using Intent as the following code:

```
Intent Intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);            
        Intent.SetType(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentType);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent, 3);
```

Now on the Intent results I run the following code to get specific contact information:

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {           
        if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == -1 && data != null) //result code -1 means OK 0 Means cancelled Result.Ok
        {
            var ContactData = data.Data;
            string ID = "";
            string name = "";
            string address = "";
            byte[] picture = new byte[0];
            List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
            List<string> emails = new List<string>();
            string mobile = "";
            string email = "";
            string selectionString  = "id = ?";



            string[] columnsNames = new string[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoUri
            };

            var loader = new CursorLoader(Statics.mainActivity, ContactData, null, null, null, null);                
            var cursor = (ICursor)loader.LoadInBackground();


            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                ID = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[0]));
                name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[1]));
                picture = cursor.GetBlob(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[2]));                  
            }

            //Store Contact ID
            string[] selectionStringArgs = new string[] { ID };

            //Phone Numbers
            string[] columnsNames2 = new string[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number                 
            };

            var loader2 = new CursorLoader(Statics.mainActivity, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, columnsNames2, selectionString, selectionStringArgs, null);
            var cursor2 = (ICursor)loader2.LoadInBackground();

            while (cursor2.MoveToNext())
            {
                numbers.Add(cursor2.GetString(cursor2.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames2[0])));
            }

            //Email Address
            string[] columnsNames3 = new string[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.Address
            };


            var loader3 = new CursorLoader(Statics.mainActivity, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri, columnsNames3, selectionString, selectionStringArgs, null);
            var cursor3 = (ICursor)loader3.LoadInBackground();

            while (cursor3.MoveToNext())
            {
                emails.Add(cursor3.GetString(cursor3.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames3[0])));
            }



            int TempRecepitntID = 0;
            EmployeesViewModel tempRecipent = new EmployeesViewModel();
            TempRecepitntID = Statics.mainActivity.currentViewModel.SelectedChat.ReceiverEmployee;

            foreach (EmployeesViewModel evm in Statics.mainActivity.currentViewModel.Employees)
            {
                if (evm.ID == TempRecepitntID)
                    tempRecipent = evm;
            }

            new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(Statics.mainActivity)
                   .SetPositiveButton("Yes", (sender1, args) =>
                   {
                       Statics.mainActivity.currentViewModel.AddMessage(picture, tempRecipent, Statics.mainActivity.currentViewModel.SelectedChat.ID, "contact", 0, "", name, numbers[0], mobile, email, address);
                   })
                   .SetNegativeButton("No", (sender1, args) =>
                   {
                        // cancel
                    })
                   .SetMessage("Are you shure you want to send?")
                   .SetTitle("System Message")
                   .Show();                
        }
    }
```

The problem is I want to retrieve only the information of the contact that the user selected but what I get is all other contacts data is retrieved so I tried to use the selection and selectionargs parameters of CursorLoader by setting string selectionString  = "id = ?"; and selectionArgs to  string[] selectionStringArgs = new string[] { ID }; the ID value is retrieved from the following code :

```
            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                ID = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[0]));
                name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[1]));
                picture = cursor.GetBlob(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[2]));                  
            }

            //Store Contact ID
            string[] selectionStringArgs = new string[] { ID };

            //Phone Numbers
            string[] columnsNames2 = new string[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number                 
            };
```

But now it returns 0 results, I couldn't find anything on the internet that applies to Xamarin android, Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution, I used the following string in the selection parameter of the cursorloader method:

string selectionString = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + "=" + ID;

and now only the selected contact numbers are retrieved.

I hope this will help someone else.

Comment: I put this after Assign the variable `ID` in the first `IF` bloque that validates cursor.movefirst()... and I get the error: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In additional information of @TMSL, I add the code afer this bloque

```
if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
                    {
                        ID = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[0]));
                        name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[1]));
                        picture = cursor.GetBlob(cursor.GetColumnIndex(columnsNames[2]));

                    }
```

Here

```
            selectionString = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + "=" + ID;
```

Then I changed the parameters used in the definition of variable `Loader2`, converting `selectionStringArgs` in `null`.

```
var loader2 = new CursorLoader(this.Activity, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, columnsNames2, selectionString, null,null);
                    var cursor2 = (ICursor)loader2.LoadInBackground();
```

I found [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/intro_to_content_providers/part_2_-_using_the_contacts_contentprovier/) documentation from xamarin guides

> - Uri – The fully qualified name of the ContentProvider.
> - Projection – Specification of which columns to select for the cursor.
> - Selection – Similar to a SQL WHERE clause.
> - SelectionArgs – Parameters to be substituted in the Selection.
> - SortOrder – Columns to sort by.

So, the variable `selectionStringArgs` used in the code from @TMSAL  cannot use a value like "contact_id = 2700", because the parameter of **CursorLoader** `SelectionArgs` is not a filter but not "Parameters to be substituted in the Selection"

I hope this will help someone else too.